# what does the socket parameter mean in the callback in socket.io/websocket?

Tags: websocket, socket.io

In `socket.io` example code we have something like this: (probably similar in other websocket framework/libraries)

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  io.emit('this', { will: 'be received by everyone'});

  socket.on('private message', function (from, msg) {
    console.log('I received a private message by ', from, ' saying ', msg);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    io.emit('user disconnected');
  });
});
```

But I am not sure what this `socket` stands for. Is it the latest connected socket?

**UPDATED**:

Suppose I have used a list to store sockets with different id:

```
let list = {};
```

Then

```
import socketActions from './socketactions';

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  return socketActions(socket, list);
}
```

in `socketactions.js`:

```
function socketActions(socket, list) {
      socket.id = Math.random();
      list[socket.id] = socket;

      socket.on('init', function(data) {
        // process data
      }

      socket.on('sendMsg', function(data) {
        // process data
      }
}

export {socketAction};
```

Because the IDs are different the sockets in the list will be different, meaning different user connections. Now somewhere in my server I want to broadcast to other users in the network:

```
for (const i in list) {
  const socket = list[i];
  socket.broadcast.emit('timeToDoSomething', handler);
}
```

Now what is the difference between the socket in the list and the socket I used in the `io.on('connection', function(socket) {});`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now what is the difference between the socket in the list and the
>   socket I used in the io.on('connection', function(socket) {});?

There is no difference, they contain the same `socket` objects.   Your code:

```
list[socket.id] = socket;
```

just saved the `socket` object into your own data structure so you could later reference it via your `list` data structure.

---

Note - you don't have to make your own map of the sockets like this.  socket.io keeps one for you already.  Instead, you can just access:

```
io.sockets.connected
```

at any time.  It is a map with the `id` as the key and the `socket` as the value.

```
// given an id, get a socket
let socket = io.sockets.connected[someSocketId];

// send a message to just that socket
socket.emit("hello");
```

---

In addition, if you want to send a message to all connected sockets, you can just use:

```
io.emit('timeToDoSomething', data);
```

This will automatically iterate through all the connected sockets and send each one the same message.

Comment: Thanks but I am putting my socket actions in a separate module and io is not exported so I use socket instead of io in the separate module. And what I don't know is the meaning of the socket inside the `io.on` callback. But I found that in `socket.io`'s github page. It means the **the incoming socket**. So basically what I am asking is the difference between **the incoming socket** and the socket I am using in the list. I wonder if they will conflict with each other in some way when I use them in the server.

Comment: @newguy - I'm just saying that a list of sockets is already maintained for you - you don't have to double maintain your own.  If you want you can export the list that already exists by just exporting `io.sockets.connected`.  You don't even have to export the whole `io` object.  Yes, `socket` in the `connection` message handler is just the incoming socket.  You are just saving that for later access as I said in my answer.

Comment: @newguy - What may cause problems in your code is overwriting the `socket.id` property.  That is already set to a unique value by socket.io.  You do not have to make your own `socket.id`.  And, in fact, when you overwrite it, you probably break some of socket.io's functionality.  If you want to create your own id, then use a different property name that won't break some of socket.io's built-in functionality.

Comment: I am currently using `let list = {};

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  return socketActions(socket, list);
});` to maintain my socket list. What do you suggest if I don't maintain a list by my own code? `socketActions` is imported from another file called `socketactions.js`. See my updated question.

Comment: @newguy - I suggested that you just use the automatically maintained list in `io.sockets.connected` rather than create your own list.   Plus, if you don't properly remove sockets from your list when the connections disconnect, you will leak memory.  I don't know what your `socketActions()` function does (no code included for that) so I don't know how to respond to any questions about that.

Comment: I don't understand what you're still asking. You are maintaining a list of sockets that is already provided for you by socket.io.  Second, you are leaking memory because you are not properly maintaining that list.  Third, you are overwriting `socket.id` which will cause some socket.io features not to work properly.  Fourth, there's nothing in `socketActions()` that needs your own list and couldn't use the built-in list.

Comment: So how can I use the built-in list in socketActions? return `socketActions(io.sockets.connected)` in `io.on`'s callback?

Comment: @newguy - The `socketActions()` code you show does not need access to a list so I have no idea what you're trying to do with a list.  But, yes you could pass `io.sockets.connected` to some other function that could then access the built-in list.  I would suggest you not change `socket.id` and don't manually modified the `io.sockets.connected` list since socket.io uses it for its own purposes, but you can use it to look up any socket you want or iterate all sockets.